# How to send a variable from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use IBM Watson visual recognition in a web application. I want to send the path of the photo uploaded by the client to a function or a controller so I can use it to build and get a result from visual recognition(build an object).
I managed to get the path like this(in internet explorer):

```
var input = document.getElementById("file");
var filepath1 = input.value;
```

I want to know how can i send the path to a controller or to a function in c#.

I also tried to build a form and add an action to the controller but the controller name didn't show up.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input accept="image/*" title="Choose an image to upload" type="file" name="file" id="file" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  [Display(Name = "My File")]
   public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model MyViewModel
<form asp-action="Send" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label asp-for="File">Filename:</label>
   <input accept="image/*" title="Choose an image to upload" type="file"  asp-for="File" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Send([Bind("File")] MyViewModel myVM)
{
   if (myVM.File?.Length > 0)
   {
            byte[] fileBytes;
            using (var fileStream = myVM.File.OpenReadStream())
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                fileStream.CopyTo(ms);
                fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }

            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(myVM.File.FileName);
            var fileMimeType = myVM.File.ContentType;
            var fileContent = fileBytes;

            //You have all the file attributes and content

   }
}
```